# Handling/displaying extremely large values in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am currently trying to perform a batch gradient descent on a toy dataset called `load_boston` obtained using the `scikit-learn` library. The dimesnions of the data set is **506 x 13** and consists of data in the order of 100's. Below is my Python script and following it are my errors upon running the script.

**boston_data_regression.py**

```
import scipy
import numpy

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

def generateGradient (X, Y, m, alpha, theta, num_iterations) :

    X_transpose = X.transpose()

    for i in range(0, num_iterations) :
        hypothesis = numpy.dot(X, theta)
        delta = hypothesis - Y
        cost = numpy.sum(delta ** 2) / (2 * m)

        print ("No. iteration : %d | Cost : %ld" % ((i + 1), cost))

        gradient = numpy.dot(X_transpose, delta) / m
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient 

    return (theta)

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    boston_data = load_boston()
    X = boston_data.data[:, 0:11]
    Y = boston_data.data[:,12]

    print (boston_data.data)

    print (numpy.shape(X))
    print (numpy.shape(Y))

    num_iterations = 100000
    alpha = 0.0005
    m, n = numpy.shape(X)

    theta = numpy.ones(n)
    theta = generateGradient(X, Y, m, alpha, theta, num_iterations)

    print (theta)
```

**Error :**

```
No. iteration : 75 | Cost : 5107568749643583921695342267251134617186569132604666005559083886757991071451800270203896531093730395389956630990780914914913406418422174358389131741568461360913005557192743665544540413282512755425657295941969706284629047517505070375172805106443882740219842668724638239205198801815953626988648840822784
No. iteration : 76 | Cost : 50304231336916560424319335120140228744355885776376593114754676052001428477104842266241766923801372402675185672996149747402542290566577918714034301765248577735574592772115140169849029676464020678156657455729204985429508262045621361912203426365153327346440580108502094724090338985744326599309593512431845376
boston_data_regression.py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  cost = numpy.sum(delta ** 2) / (2 * m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boston_data_regression.py", line 38, in <module>
    theta = generateGradient(X, Y, m, alpha, theta, num_iterations)
  File "boston_data_regression.py", line 15, in generateGradient
    print ("No. iteration : %d | Cost : %ld" % ((i + 1), cost))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not numpy.float64
```

May I know how to sort this error and if there is a better/more optimized manner of performing batch gradient descent?

Comment: Your values are quite close to the maximum of `numpy.float64`. If you check `numpy.finfo('d')` you will find that the maximum value is around `1.8e+308`. Your value at iteration 76 is already at `5.0e+304` and may increase beyond the maximum value in the subsequent step.

Comment: @ChristophEngwer So is there a way to sort things out without changing the values belonging to the data set or should I resort to **feature scaling** instead?

Comment: I'd check the value for `cost` each time step with a direct print, i.e. not via string formatting. If your value is higher than `1.8e+308` it will give you `numpy.inf`instead of its actual value. If this is the case, you should probably scale down your values.

Comment: @ChristophEngwer If you could write it as an answer, I'd upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I put my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises from the dimensions of your values. Your values steadily increase up to `5.e+304` and an error is raised in the subsequent time step which probably comes from an overflow.

You can check the limits for `numpy.float64` values with:

```
import numpy
numpy.finfo('d')
finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

As you can see, the maximum value is around `1.8e+308`. A solution to this problem is to scale down the values.